# Accessing Methods in my WCF Services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

If I have a WCF service and I'm trying to access a method in that service.

For example:

```
TestObject test = new TestObject("Test Title");
MyService myNewService = new MyService();
myNewService.SaveObjectToDataBase(test);
```

Why is it that I get an error saying that the argument list expects a data type `MyConsoleApplication.MyService.TestObject` rather than `TestObject`?

It was not doing this before I updated my service reference. I don't think I changed any relevant properties that would cause this.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

**EDIT**

The `SaveObjectToDataBase()` expects a parameter of type `TestObject` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a service reference, there is an option to re-use existing classes in the proxy that is generated. If you don't do this, it creates custom classes for the interface which, while they may match yours by name and properties, are not the same. Try updating the service reference again, and keep an eye out for this option. You get to it by clicking on the **Advanced...** button - it's the ticked one here:

[image]

Comment: Hey David,

Thanks for the quick answer. My settings for my service reference are the same as what you posted as a picture... For some reason, it is not reusing the proper types. So weird

Comment: Did you have a reference to the assembly containing `TestObject` before you updated the service reference, or has that been added subsequently?

Comment: I have a reference to the DLL that contains the class TestObject and it was always there. It started when I did an update to my service reference. Im stumped on this one!

Comment: Delete the service reference and re-add it?

Comment: I dont think I have a choice anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try. You could check that the service type dll and the project you are adding have compatible .NET version. In the project that is creating service reference, set the Target framework to non Client Profile.